# How to ask user whether to overwrite an existing file when installing an higher version?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Recently I was creating a Windows Installer package using a WiX Setup project, and I have following requirements:

1. When copying a versioned file to the Windows System32 folder, if the same file with a higher version is present then I should not overwrite.
2. If a lower version is present, I need to overwrite the file.

Before doing this, the user should get a warning message like "File exists, do you wish to overwrite?".

Any suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: Windows Installer doesn't support this.

Answer (score 2):

Windows Installer handles the overwrite decision as you described but does not ask the user.

A couple suggestions in the "**don't do this**" category:

1. Although it was common a couple of decades ago for installers to have such a feature, the vast majority of users are not knowledgeable enough to make the decision; those that are probably would not like to make the decision anyway. You should *not* ask them to do so.
2. Application frameworks have evolved to the point where putting files in System32 is usually not necessary. In particular, if your application depends on a third-party library, use its installer to handle its installation. You can use WiX Bootstrapper project to chain the installers together (WiX 3.6 or later).